# Implementing Open Source Library: How to handle logging?

Tags: .net, logging

I am in the process of implementing logging support in an open source library I am working on. Most 3rd party libraries seem to explicitly choose a "preferred" logging library such as [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) etc and then require that the consumer of their library "deal with it". Thankfully, we have a library like [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) to address this issue in our consuming application(s) that unifies these 3rd party library logging implementations.

I was going to try and avoid referencing another 3rd party library from my own open source library to avoid bringing in yet another assembly reference in to someone else's application. Perhaps this is not a concern, and I should just stop there?

Assuming that some people agree that excessive assembly references are annoying (and since someone will mention it), I personally, I don't like using ILMerge for this type of situation, as you may easily have several libraries that use Log4Net and if they each ILMerged in the assembly it is just bloating the size of an application in my opinion.

To that end, I was thinking of implementing and exposing a LogBridge to allow the consumer of my library to hook in to my logging calls if so desired (would be off by default). *Also let me stress that I am not talking about implementing my own logging framework, just ensuring that I expose logging if someone is concerned with comsuming it.* I was thinking the consuming implementation would appear something like:

```
public class SomeSetupClass 
{
  private void SomeSetupMethod()
  {
    var log = LogManager.GetLogger("LogSourceName");
    var logBridge = new LogBridge()
                      {
                        DebugEnabled = log.IsDebugEnabled,
                        InformationEnabled = log.IsInfoEnabled,
                        WarningEnabled = log.IsWarnEnabled,
                        ErrorEnabled = log.IsErrorEnabled,
                        CriticalEnabled = log.IsFatalEnabled
                      };

    logBridge.DebugMessageReceived += (sender, e) => log.Debug(e.Message);
    logBridge.InformationMessageReceived += (sender, e) => log.Info(e.Message);
    logBridge.WarningMessageReceived += (sender, e) => log.Warn(e.Message);
    logBridge.ErrorMessageReceived += (sender, e) => log.Error(e.Message);
    logBridge.CrticalMessageReceived += (sender, e) => log.Fatal(e.Message);      }
  }
}
```

Does this approach make sense? Am I over thinking this after being on vacation for too long and I should just reference [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) etc and be done with it? Am I missing any major cons of this approach? Does the rough API make sense?

As always, curious what everyone thinks...

**Update**

Curious if people think that jgauffin solution is the better way to go? I had given it some thought prior to this post; my thought was that the LogBridge would be easier to hook up for consumers rather than requiring a custom interface to be implemented in a consuming project? Thoughts?

Comment: Something like this makes good sense. There are numerous logging frameworks out there--some better than others. Everyone has their favorite. By providing a nice hook as you are doing, you aren't shoving anything down anyone's throat, and you are providing excellent flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in System.Diagnostics and just use the Trace or Debug classes.  Products like Log4Net can pick those up when needed.

Comment: Yeah, I had considered this as well. I looked at how to implement a CustomTraceListener, and although you can override the handling of TraceEvent; the API seemed to expect that you override Write/WriteLine at which point you lose the TraveEventLevel. Issue/Non-issue?

Comment: Non issue -- you're inheriting from the base trace listener, and so you can still build your WriteLine() method to take that into account (if you want to).

Comment: Fair enough... that was my original plan anways... only started to consider an alternative when I saw that Write/WriteLine were abstract and had to be overriden... thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

1. Provide a interface for logging: `ILogger`
2. Create a logger factory used to fetch a logger: `ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClassBeingLogged));`
3. Provide a basic implementation such as ConsoleLogger.

You can also provide examples in your project wiki showing how to implement nlog or log4net. That's usually enough.

the LogManager takes a `ILogFactory` which is responsible of creating the actual implementation:

```
public class LogManager
{ 
    ILogFactory _factory;

    public static void Assign(ILogFactory factory);
    public static ILogger GetLogger(Type typeBeingLogged);
}

public interface ILogFactory
{
    ILogger GetLogger(Type typeBeingLogged);
}
```

This makes it quite easy to implement an adapter for any logging framework.

Comment: I had given some thought to this approach; my thought is that the main drawback is that a user must implement and inject an implementation of your logging interface. My initial impression is that would be more work for the consumer than just binding their existing logging framework to a very simple LogBridge API. That being said, examples in the project Wiki is a must as you point out. Thoughts?

Comment: It's usually only two classes that needs to implemented to get it working. You can also make a nlog or log4net implementation that you ilmerge (I don't mean that you should ilmerge log4net/nlog, but the adapters for the frameworks) and provide separate downloads on your site. The users can still use their favorite logging framework since the main download only got interfaces defined.